# Django one model for two model form

Tags: django, forms, model

I am newbie on Django. I have one model and two forms that can be accessed with different url. I have two different table on my database when I fill forms. What I want is to have one table on the database. What should I do?

Here is my forms:

```
class customerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = customerInfoModel
        fields = (
            "customerName",
                 )

class addCustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = customerInfoModel
        fields = (
            "user",
            "passwd",
            )
```

Here is my model:

```
class customerInfoModel(models.Model):
     customerName = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
     user = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
     passwd = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
```

Views.py

```
@login_required
def addCustomer(request):
    form = customerForm(request.POST or None)
    content = {"form" : form,}
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        name = form.cleaned_data['customerName']
        messages.success(request,"{} successfully added.".format(name))
        return redirect("addproduct")

    else:
        return render(request,"addcustomer.html",content)



@login_required
def addProduct(request):
    form = addCustomerForm(request.POST or None)
    content = {"form" : form,}
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.success(request,"product successfully added.")
    return redirect("addproduct")
return render(request,"addproduct.html",content)
```

EDIT:

If I fill both forms, I want to have two objects. One object using `customerForm` should have an output of `customername : 'kartal'`, `user: ''`, `passwd: ''`; the other object using `addCustomerForm` has `customername: ''`, `user: 'test'`, `passwd: 'test'`. I want one object something like that `customername: 'kartal'`, `user:'test'`, `passwd:'test'`

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? Add error details

Comment: can you share your views.py here?